# Excel VBA: Webpage HTML not showing when I navigate to new page

Tags: html, vba, excel

I'm trying to create a VBA macro in Excel that:

1. Navigates to a webpage
2. Searches the HTML document for all elements with the tag name "input"
3. Prints the attributes of each element found (name, type, and value)
4. Clicks the button on the webpage to navigate to the second webpage.
5. Search the HTML document on the second page for all elements with the tag name "input"
6. Prints the attributes of each element found (name, type, and value)

Everything works find up until Step 5. When I try to search the HTML document, for some reason it doesn't search the HTML document of the second page, instead it looks at the HTML of the initial webpage in Step 2 and prints out the same results in Step 3.

Could you guys please take a look at my code to see what I am doing wrong? I listed my code below and tried to make comments to make it readable.

```
Sub C_R()

Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement


'Opens Internet Explorer and navigates to website.
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "http://openaccess.sb-court.org/OpenAccess/"

        Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Loop


'Searches HTML(initial page) to find all elements with "input" tag name.
'Prints attributes of each element (name, type, and value".

Set HTMLDoc = ie.Document
Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")

    Debug.Print "Initial Page"

    For Each HTMLButton In HTMLButtons
        Debug.Print HTMLButton.getAttribute("name"), HTMLButton.getAttribute("type"), HTMLButton.getAttribute("value")
    Next HTMLButton
'Navigates to second page

    HTMLButtons(1).Click

    Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

'Searches HTML(second page) to find all elements with "input" tag name.
'Prints attributes of each element (name, type, and value".

Set HTMLDoc = ie.Document
Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")

    Debug.Print "Second Page"

    For Each HTMLButton In HTMLButtons
        Debug.Print HTMLButton.getAttribute("name"), HTMLButton.getAttribute("type"), HTMLButton.getAttribute("value")
    Next HTMLButton
End Sub
```

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Did the IE change page after the first `HTMLButtons(1).Click`? I would use Firefox and with Developer Tools, you can see changes to html codes when you click buttons in real time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your second loop is continuing even though the webpage hasn't completely loaded.

```
    Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
```

To see this, put a break point at the second loop, and wait for the second web page to load. Then continue the code, and it should work fine.

You will need to either add a wait time in the loop, which may not always work, or find another way to tell if the ie.ReadyState is complete.